# where is JSR-97 (JavaHelp)

Tags: java, jsr, javahelp

Since the Sun->Oracle transition, the search for java-documentation has been a mess. I'm looking to find the official JSR-97 specs:

http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr097/index.html

Clicking on the link leads a redirecting page, ending up clicking in circles.

Answer (score 0):

At first you can check here for JSR-97: http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=97
JavaHelp 2.0 has been released and is now FCS. It's page is: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javahelp/ However the JavaHelp project has moved to https://javahelp.dev.java.net/

Comment: dev.java.net syays: "Migration notice: Projects that have been locked for migration are available at the URL <projectname>.java.net. These pages have not been forwarded yet because archived mailing lists and documents have not been imported to the new site and are only available here for now." Are you looking for this: http://www.scribd.com/doc/6867489/javahelp20spec  ?

Comment: As I can see it now, there is not official location for the JSR-97 specifications, which is *not* good. Let's hope this is a temporary situation.

Answer (score 0):

The details about the JSR are available [JSR-97](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=97).  The last JAVA EE based code based was released to github at [GitHub JavaEE - Java Help Repo](https://github.com/javaee/javahelp) which is read only.