# What is the current status of JavaHelp Java API?

Tags: java, javahelp

While reviewing old Java project code, which relied on [*JavaHelp*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaHelp) Java API to provide help functionality, it was unclear what the current status of this API is.

The Java Help API spec is defined as part of [JSR-97](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=97).

The [JavaHelp Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaHelp) seems to imply it was donated / opened sources to github as part of the [Java EE JavaHelp](https://github.com/javaee/javahelp) project.  However, this project has been archived.

There was licensing concern (i.e., it was GPLv2 with exception, relicenses to CDDL partly with some still being GPLv2 with exceptions) .

Most of the Java EE source has transitioned to the Eclipse / [Jakarta EE project](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j).  But it's unclear if the JavaHelp functionality was picked up for further development under this umbrella.

There is some [legacy JavaHelp documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-0913/819-0913.pdf) but this provides details on usage and points to communities and email addresses which are no longer applicable.

Similar [stackoverflow question was asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919143/where-is-jsr-97-javahelp/4919295) which had some response but may be a bit dated.

Assume "Java Help" may no longer be of use or OBE, preferring instead to use some form of "web based" help content but not sure if this is 100% the case and the official transition expectations.

1. What is the status of Java Help given transitions and upgrades presently?
2. Is there still any value in the "Java Help" API?
3. What is the alternative to this?

Comment: For (3) : You might want to try **Oracle Help**. It is very similar to JavaHelp, but more actively maintained (I think this also answers (1) and (2) for you to some extent)

Comment: @ken-lee assume this means [Oracle Help](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/jdev/api-reference-ohj/overview-summary.html) which is associated with [JDeveloper](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/jdev/) right?

Comment: I guess the downvotes/closures were because you asked multiple questions and at least two of them are open ended. These questions are more fit for a discussion forum, not for a question & answer site. At least I can tell you JavaHelp is definitely not (going to be) part of JEE. You might want to correct this misassumption in the question too.

Comment: @BalusC appreciate the feedback.  Ha